# Add border to excel using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to add a border around my dataframe which i have created using pandas as shown in the attached picture[ExcelTableImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YPpC.png). Below is my code snippet. How can this be done?

```
[df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2=pd.DataFrame(exportFields)
df2 = df2.transpose()
# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Users/roshni.j/Desktop/Clarivoy_docs/Testing/pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')


# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False, header=False,startcol=1, startrow=2)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False, header=False,startcol=1, startrow=3)


# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use something like StyleFrame for this (https://styleframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Pure pandas can't draw any frames in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Use `add_table` method from pandas  then you can style it.
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_tables.html